# How can I have my ZeroMQ app reject additional connections?

Tags: networking, zeromq

I have a C++ 0MQ application that does a `bind()` and sends messages using a `PUSH` socket. I want to ensure that these messages get sent to no more than one client.

**Is there a way to allow just one client to `.connect()`**, and then reject connections from all subsequent clients?

Answer (score 0):

If your server application uses a ROUTER socket instead of PUSH, it has more control over the connections. The first frame of each message contains the id of the sender, so the server can treat one connection specially.

To make this work, the protocol has to be a little more complicated than a simple PUSH/PULL. One way is for the connections to be DEALER sockets, whose first action is to sent an "I'm here" message to the server. The server then knows the id of the connections, and treats the first one specially. Any other connections can be rejected with a "You shouldn't be here" message to the other connections, which of course they must understand and act on it by disconnecting themselves.

After the first "I'm here" message, the clients do not need to send any more messages. They can just sit there waiting for messages from the server, exactly the same as PUSH/PULL.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, there is

While the genuine ZeroMQ messaging framework has lot of built-in features, it allows to integrate additional abstract layers, that can solve your task and many other, custom-specific, needs. So do not worry that there is not a direct API call for doing what you need.

### How to do it?

Assuming your formal architecture is given, the viable approach would be to re-use networking security trick known as "**port-knocking**".

This trick adds an "introduction" phase on a publicly known **`aPortToKnockAt`**, after which ( upon having successfully met the condition(s) -- in your case being the first client to have asked for / to have completed a `.connect()` -- another, working, port is being used privately for a "transport" phase ( and in your case, the original port is being closed ).

This way your application does not devastate either local-side, or the remote-side resources as **`aPortToKnockAt`** provides means to protect soliton-archetype only handshaking and forthcoming attempts to knock there will find just a **`.close()`**-ed door ( and will handle that remotely ), so a sort of a very efficient passive reject is being achieved.